I'm trying to sync files (upon create and modify) from a specific MS Sharepoint library to Google Drive
I'm trying to sync files (upon create and modify) from a specific MS Sharepoint library to Google Drive.
I want to do it without a 3rd party product.
I've been using powerautomate, and it works, but only connecting to a google drive, not a shared google drive.
I can't change the powerautomate connector to find, let alone use the shared drive. I created the drive from my G Workpace account as a shared drive....
Please help....
I've tried manipulating the URL/destination location, but that just creates a structure under my google workspace drive and not the shared - even when i use the share drive's URL, the connector replicates that name under my google drive.
